# How to connect to a docker container database on a remote ubuntu server?

Tags: mysql, docker, ubuntu

I've tried searching left and right and I can't find a solution to my problem. I can connect perfectly fine on my localhost to my docker container's database (simply by connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1/ubuntuip) on dbeaver, but when it comes to connecting to my docker mysql container on the remote ubuntu server (so not the ubuntu running on my computer), it doesn't work.

**Things I've tried**

- Connecting to the ubuntu server ip (by doing "hostname -I";
- Connecting to the ip shown when I run "curl http://checkip.amazonaws.com" on the remote ubuntu server (I ssh into it);
- Connecting to the docker container ip when I do `inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id` on the remote ubuntu server.

None of those worked and I'm getting a bit lost honestly. When I do `select host, user from mysql.user` on the remote ubuntu server, I get this :

```
mysql> select host, user from mysql.user;

+-----------+------------------+
| host      | user             |
+-----------+------------------+
| %         | root             |
| localhost | mysql.infoschema |
| localhost | mysql.session    |
| localhost | mysql.sys        |
| localhost | root             |
+-----------+------------------+
```

From what I understand, I should be able to connect to it since I allow any host (this is dev, not prod). I can easily ping my db container, the tables are created fine in it and everything. I just can't connect to it from my Dbeaver.

Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: How did you start the container?  Are there firewalls on either the local or remote systems?  I'd generally expect you should be able to connect to the remote database using the same host name you ssh to, and the first port number from your `docker run -p` option.  (Not really any different from running the database on a remote host but not in Docker.)

Comment: Hello, I start it using docker-compose (I don't know if you remember, but you had helped me a few weeks ago with it). The ports in the docker-compose are 3306:3306. The following image shows the running ports of the containers : https://i.imgur.com/diNn1gO.png

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Just like David Maze said, I had to connect to the same url as the one I used to ssh, but I had already tried that. What I had to do was to also go in the SSH tab on dbeaver and add the host (same url) and select the auth method to "public key" and I selected my ssh key folder (id_rsa) which is located at `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\home\user\.ssh\id_rsa`. I left the "passphrase" blank and now it works!

Thanks for the help!